# Cannot access to cell text inside an html table (Selenium,python)

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, automation, lxml.html

I have been trying for a few hours now to extract a text from a specific cell in the following table for vain:

```
<tbody class="table-body">
   <tr class=" " data-blah="25293454534534513" data-currency="1">
      <td class="action-cell no-sort">
         <a href="" class="buy-btn tooltip" data-tooltip="Buy the bond"></a><a href="" class="sell-btn tooltip" data-tooltip="Sell the bond"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="col1 id">
         <a class="alert-ico " data-tooltip=""></a>
         <a class="isin-btn " data-tooltip="" id="isin" data-portfolioid="2423424" data-status="0">US3</a>
      </td>
      <td class="col2 name hide">4%</td>
      <td class="col9 colNo.9" title="Bid: 101.23; Mid: 101.28; Ask: 101.33; 
         Liquidity Score: -*/5*; Merit: -/4;" data-bprice="101.28" data-uprice="101.28">101.28<span class="estim-star">*</span></td>
      <td class="col10 price_change" nowrap="" data-sort="0.02"><span class="positive-change">0.02%</span><span class="change-sign positive-change">↑</span></td>
      <td class="col11 yield yield-val" title="" data-sort="3.33" data-byield="3.33" data-uyield="3.34%">3.33%</td>
      <td class="col12 purchase_price" data-bprice="101.28" data-uprice="101.28" data-sort="101.28"><input type="text" name="purchase_price" class="positive-num-only default" value="101.28"></td>
      <td class="col13 margin_bond" data-bond="sec" data-sort="0"><input type="text" name="margin_bond" maxlength="3" class="positive-num-only default" value="0"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to extract a text from column 'Price Change' (col 10) using lxml.html which allows me to extract data from big tables in a manner of seconds. I'm doing it like that:

```
import lxml.html
import pandas as pd
root = lxml.html.fromstring(self.driver.page_source)
data = []
for row in root.xpath('.//*[@id=\'main\']/div[5]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr'):
    cells = row.xpath('.//td/text()')
```

So, I succeeded to extract the whole table like that and I know that the only exception is column 10 ('price change') and tried the following and it returned the empty string (""):

1. row.xpath('.//tr[1]/td[11][@data-sort]/text()')
2. row.xpath('.//[@id='main']/div[5]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[11]/span/text()')
3. row.xpath('.//*[@id='main']/div[5]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[11]/text()')

**I don't want to extract the text using WebElement but only with lxml.html library**

Thank you!

Comment: what does this returns `root.xpath("//table[@class='table-body']//td[contains(class,'col10')])/span` check the value in watchlist or debugger. what text does it contains?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

1. There are total 7 **tds** and not **11**, the td you are intersted is 5 and not 11.
2. the td you are intersted in has two span and you are not providing which span you are interested in.

this code works perfectly fine.

```
html_code = """
<tbody class="table-body">
   <tr class=" " data-blah="25293454534534513" data-currency="1">
      <td class="action-cell no-sort">
         <a href="" class="buy-btn tooltip" data-tooltip="Buy the bond"></a><a href="" class="sell-btn tooltip" data-tooltip="Sell the bond"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="col1 id">
         <a class="alert-ico " data-tooltip=""></a>
         <a class="isin-btn " data-tooltip="" id="isin" data-portfolioid="2423424" data-status="0">US3</a>
      </td>
      <td class="col2 name hide">4%</td>
      <td class="col9 colNo.9" title="Bid: 101.23; Mid: 101.28; Ask: 101.33;
         Liquidity Score: -*/5*; Merit: -/4;" data-bprice="101.28" data-uprice="101.28">101.28<span class="estim-star">*</span></td>
      <td class="col10 price_change" nowrap="" data-sort="0.02">
        <span class="positive-change">0.02%</span>
        <span class="change-sign positive-change">↑</span></td>
      <td class="col11 yield yield-val" title="" data-sort="3.33" data-byield="3.33" data-uyield="3.34%">3.33%</td>
      <td class="col12 purchase_price" data-bprice="101.28" data-uprice="101.28" data-sort="101.28"><input type="text" name="purchase_price" class="positive-num-only default" value="101.28"></td>
      <td class="col13 margin_bond" data-bond="sec" data-sort="0"><input type="text" name="margin_bond" maxlength="3" class="positive-num-only default" value="0"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
"""


tree = html.fromstring(html_code)

print "purchase price is %s" % tree.xpath(".//td[contains(@class,'col10')]/span[1]/text()")[0]
print "purchase price is %s" % tree.xpath(".//td[5]/span[1]/text()")[0]
```